# Optimized Conversion Pixel in FB ads (import CSV)

Tags: facebook, import, ads

How to set up 'Optimized Conversion Pixel' in FB campaigns, using CSV importing.

I tried with this set up:
 -Bid Type: 'multi absolute'
 -Conversion Tracking Pixel: pixelID;
 -Conversion Specs: [{"action.type":["offsite_conversion"],"offsite_pixel":["pixelID"]}]
 -Optimized Conversion Tracking Pixel: pixelID

I also try to set up:
 -Additional Custom Tracking Specs:["offsite_conversion"],"offsite_pixel":["pixelID"]}]
and :
 -Bid type: ABSOLUTE_OCPM ([https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversion-specs/)

But, when I import CSV in Power Editor, there is no 'Optimized Conversion Pixel'

So please tell me is it posible to set up OCP in this way, and if it is, what I'm doing wrong ??